# Merge / Group records to a single line

Tags: sql

I have a single order line in which i have connected two charges PNP and HAN to the order line and i need for them to show on a single line in a report to show the two charge values connected to the order line.

Below is the table example of the current output;

| OBORNO | OBPONR | OBITNO | OBHDPR | OBSAPR | PNP_CHG_AMT | HAN_CHG_AMT | FIN_SLS_PRC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000000096 | 1.0 | 1000020-0001 | 1000020 | 10.00 | 0.00 | 0.15 | 0.00 |
| 2000000096 | 1.0 | 1000020-0001 | 1000020 | 10.00 | 2.55 | 0.00 | 12.55 |

Desired Output;

| OBORNO | OBPONR | OBITNO | OBHDPR | OBSAPR | PNP_CHG_AMT | HAN_CHG_AMT | FIN_SLS_PRC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000000096 | 1.0 | 1000020-0001 | 1000020 | 10.00 | 2.55 | 0.15 | 12.55 |

Here is my statement so far;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
OBORNO,
OBITNO,
OBHDPR,
OBSAPR,
CASE WHEN O7CRID = 'PNP' THEN OBORQA * O7CRAM
    ELSE 0
END AS PNP_CHARGE_AMT,

CASE WHEN O7CRID = 'HAN' THEN OBORQA * O7CRAM
    ELSE 0
END AS HAN_CHARGE_AMT,

CASE WHEN O7CRID = 'PNP' THEN (OBORQA * O7CRAM) + OBSAPR
    ELSE 0
END AS FINAL_SLS_PRC

FROM [MVXJDTA].[OOLINE]
LEFT JOIN [MVXJDTA].[OOLICH] ON O7CONO = OBCONO
    AND O7ORNO = OBORNO
    AND O7PONR = OBPONR
WHERE OBCONO = '610' 
    AND OBORNO = '2000000096'
```

Comment: Sure, just group by `OBORNO, OBITNO, OBHDPR, OBSAPR` and `SUM()` the amount columns.

Comment: Like, you can just wrap those CASE WHEN statements in SUM().  As in, `SUM(CASE WHEN O7CRID = 'PNP' THEN OBORQA * O7CRAM ELSE 0 END ) AS [PNP_CHARGE_AMT]`.

Comment: @MarkMoretto omg I can't believe i overlooked the GROUP BY....  Yes, this has worked and i have achieved my desired result.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Select OBORNO,
       MAX(OBPONR),
       MAX(OBITNO),
       MAX(OBHDPR),
       MAX(OBSAPR), 
       SUM(PNP_CHG_AMT),
       SUM(HAN_CHG_AMT),
       SUM(FIN_SLS_PRC)
FROM table
GROUP BY OBORNO
```

Comment: Probably the last three columns require a `SUM()` rather than a `MAX()`. But... it's not clear in the question. +1